# Read Array[Struct] from file swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, file, struct

I have this struct

```
struct Question {
  let answer : String
  let questionText : String
}
```

Then I have an array of this struct

```
var questions = [Question]()
```

How can I read array from .txt file (because I have over 300 lines of array)?

```
questions = [
    Question(answer:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",questionText:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"),
    Question(answer:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",questionText:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"),
    ...
]
```

Comment: You should use json or plist file instead of txt

Comment: @LeoDabus Could you show me an example?